# Complement of bounded set in C proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to ***show that the complement of every bounded set in $\mathbb{C}$ is unbounded***. I'm not familiar with how to manipulate the complement of the bounded set to show that it is unbounded and would appreciate some guidance on how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Just consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. A bounded set can only contain a finite number of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your definition of bounded? If you say a set is bounded if it is contained in a ball of finite radius, then what happens to its complement? Its complement must contain the complement of that ball with finite radius. In particular you could make the ball centered at the origin with radius $r$. Then its complement is $\{x\in\mathbb C\;\vert\;\lvert x\rvert\ge r\}$, which is clearly not contained in a ball of finite radius.